# Style the <hr /> tag in GAS

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a few `<hr />` tags I want to use in a Ui. I want to set the color of the horizontal line, but no matter what color I put in there it remains a dull gray. Also the line does not grow vertically when I try to adjust the set size property. I can set the background color and the background color responds to the adjustment of the size property. Here is the line of code:

```
app.createHTML("<hr />").setSize(980,10).setStyleAttribute("color", "black");
```

Is this a bug or? Or am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about this:

```
app.createHTML("<hr />").setStyleAttribute("height", "10px").setStyleAttribute("background", "black").setStyleAttribute("border", "black");
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It still produces the same problem using this method.

Comment: you cannot set style `color:black`, because only IE recognizes that as a style for `HR`. which browser are you using ?

Comment: Ideally it would be great to have it work in IE,Firefox, and Chrome.

Comment: Here is a link to a screenshot I took from the Ui. This is the effect that is being produced. The background color works fine, but there is always a grey rectangular outline above it, which looks horrible. This pic was taken using the code you supplied above. My original code and your code produce this same effect.
Here is the link:
http://goo.gl/58F7z

Comment: Hello, the problem still exists. I checked it with Firefox and chrome. I think this has to be a bug. Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: you could always analyze what that extra line is using dev tools in chrome.